Cloud Composer (Airflow)- DAG test_dag scheduling was skipped, probably because the DAG record was locked
When trying to run tasks in for loop, the scheduler logs shows - 'DAG test_dag scheduling was skipped, probably because the DAG record was locked' and DAG fails after sometime.
When tried to execute the task in sequence (one after another) , it works fine.
Its single scheduler pod and restarting it isnt ideal for production.
Below is code snippet that causes issue, there are just 4 SQL files from the for loop.
...

directory_path = '/home/airflow/gcs/data/test_dag/sql'
file_contents = {}
for filename in filenames:
    try:
        print(f"Processing file: {filename}")
        with open(os.path.join(directory_path, filename), 'r') as file:
            template = Template(file.read())
            query = template.render(**env)
            file_contents[filename] = query
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing file {filename}: {e}")


 taskA >> taskB
    previous_task = bq_streaming_buffer_wait
    for filename, content in file_contents.items():
        try:
            execute_query_task = PythonOperator(
                task_id=f'execute_query_{filename.replace(".sql", "")}',
                python_callable=execute_query,
                op_args=[filename, content],
                provide_context=True,
                trigger_rule=TriggerRule.NONE_SKIPPED
            )
            taskB >> taskC
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error creating task for file {filename}: {e}")

PythonOperator here executes a SQL query.
How could this be resolved ?
Is there any config tuning that could resolve this ?
Help is appreciated

The lock message is probably not related and only appear due to using more than 1 scheduler. Where do file_contents comes from? Airflow task are expected to as static as possible. If file_contents changes often then you should use mapped tasks  https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html

hello @EladKalif, file_contents are stored under /data bucket gcs location - /home/airflow/gcs/data/test_dag/sql, im uploading files from tf to the gcs location, and reading outside dag
eg
`
env = os.environ.copy()
directory_path = '/home/airflow/gcs/data/test_dag/sql'
for filename in filenames:
print(f"Processing file: {filename}")
with open(os.path.join(directory_path, filename), 'r') as file:
template = Template(file.read())
query = template.render(**env)
file_contents[filename] = query
with DAG(
...
) as dag:
`

@EladKalif i updated the original post to include the file reading part,
do u feel there is issue here ?
